# Blender 3.5 Unsupportyed graphics card

Tags: drivers, installation

Having issues both with meshmixer and blender failing on launch, blender gives me an error regarding a graphics card and drivers not able to support OpenGL 3.3

Currently running a radeon 6600 XT with adrenalin 23.q1.1 as a driver

I've tried reinstalling programs, drivers, and enabling/ reenabling the GPU without success. As far as I'm able to tell, I think this graphics card should be sufficient and previously ran both programs with it several months ago?

Comment: Please don't ask two identical questions within minutes of each other!

Comment: Hi, Erik, this appears to be a duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/293256/blender-3-5-unsupportyed-graphics-card, so has been deleted for you