# Blender 3.5 Unsupported graphics card

Tags: drivers, installation

Having issues both with [Meshmixer](https://meshmixer.com/) and Blender failing on launch, Blender gives me an error regarding a graphics card and drivers not able to support OpenGL 3.3.

Currently running a radeon 6600 XT with adrenalin 23.q1.1 as a driver.

I've tried reinstalling programs, drivers, and enabling/reenabling the GPU without success. As far as I'm able to tell, I think this graphics card should be sufficient and previously ran both programs with it several months ago?

Comment: @ThomasWeller that's the (probably accidentally) created duplicate question that got closed as a duplicate of this question. We have now a loop ;-)

Comment: @Erik Olson, your Radeon 6600 XT graphics card is fine. It supports OpenGL 4.6. Do you have a CPU with an integrated GPU (iGPU)? Intel CPU w/o a "K" in the name? There are some guys who had the same problem. It reason was that they connected their monitor to the mainboard's HDMI port (=iGPU) and not to the graphics card's port so the system uses the wrong GPU => https://community.amd.com/t5/opengl-vulkan/amd-radeon-rx-580-has-a-adrenalin-edition-22-5-2-driver-issue/m-p/529520 and https://community.amd.com/t5/opengl-vulkan/radeon-rx-6800-xt-opengl-is-stuck-at-1-1-instead-of-4-6-or/m-p/528536.

Comment: And this one https://community.amd.com/t5/opengl-vulkan/radeon-rx-6600-opengl-issues/m-p/529656 (which refers to the other two links)

Comment: (sorry, I messed it up. The [letter 'F'](https://www.cgdirector.com/intel-k-vs-kf-vs-f-cpus/) means for Intel CPUs that there is *no* onboard graphics/*no* iGPU)

Comment: No worries, that was the issue! Thanks for the help!